# How can I convert scala.xml.Elem to something compatible with the javax.xml APIs?

Tags: java, xml, scala, interop

I have a Scala representation of some XML (i.e. a [`scala.xml.Elem`](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/api/scala/xml/Elem.html)), and I'd like to use it with some of the standard Java XML APIs (specifically [SchemaFactory](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/SchemaFactory.html)).  It looks like converting my `Elem` to a [`javax.xml.transform.Source`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Source.html) is what I need to do, but I'm not sure.  I can see various ways to effectively write out my `Elem` and read it into something compatible with Java, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant (and hopefully more efficient) approach?

Scala code:

```
import java.io.StringReader
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource
import javax.xml.validation.{Schema, SchemaFactory}
import javax.xml.XMLConstants

val schemaXml = <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                  <xsd:element name="foo"/>
                </xsd:schema>
val schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

// not possible, but what I want:
// val schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaXml)

// what I'm actually doing at present (ugly)
val schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(new StreamSource(new StringReader(schemaXml.toString)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is *possible* - you just have to gently tell the Scala compiler how to go from `scala.xml.Elem` to `javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource` by declaring an *implicit method*.

```
import java.io.StringReader
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource
import javax.xml.validation.{Schema, SchemaFactory}
import javax.xml.XMLConstants
import scala.xml.Elem

val schemaXml = <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                  <xsd:element name="foo"/>
                </xsd:schema>
val schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

implicit def toStreamSource(x:Elem) = new StreamSource(new StringReader(x.toString))

// Very possible, possibly still not any good:
val schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaXml)
```

It isn't any more efficient, but it sure is prettier once you get the implicit method definition out of the way.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  While it's definitely nicer looking this way, it is still writing the Elem out to a String and reading it back in, which I was hoping to avoid.

Comment: Since alternatives aren't exactly flooding in, I'm going to accept this answer (I've also stuck with this approach in my app).  Thanks.

Comment: No problem. I wish I knew of a better answer, but I'm not too familiar with Java. I'm jumping back into the Java ecosystem because of Scala. At least this way your code will be more concise.